# Not able to load a custom dataset

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning, dataset

I want to train a CNN classifier in keras but my custom made dataset. I have created the CNN model but I am totally confused on how to input my dataset into the train, valid and test sets. I am new to deep learning. I have 7 types of classes namely `['A','C','F','L','N','R','V']` but these are included with the images names. My image names would be as `MLII_C_1.jpeg or V1_C_1.jpeg`. The middle letter in the image names gives me the class it belongs to. How can I load my images? and make by target labels. Please, someone, help me.
[image: My dataset folder]

Comment: This question is too broad to answer directly. Have a look at the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) method and the [`imread`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html) method from the  `imageio` library

Answer (score 1):

I believe [ImageDataGenerator()](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) is one of the easiest way to do that, 
Let's assume you have data (images) divided into training, validation, and testing in the following hierarchy:

```
train-| class1
      | class2 
      . 
      .
      | classN 


valid-| class1
      | class2 
      . 
      .
      | classN 


test- | class1
      | class2 
      . 
      .
      | classN
```

then in python start by specifying the path like:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_path = "Path"
valid_path = "Path"
test_path =  "Path"
```

then simply use this:

```
trainBatches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['class1', 'class2', .. , 'classn'], batch_size=64)
valBatches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(valid_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['class1', 'class2', .. , 'classn'], batch_size=32)
testBatches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['class1', 'class2', .. , 'classn'], batch_size=32)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to write all the classes in here 'classes=['class1', 'class2', .. , 'classn']', in your case: classes=['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class5', 'class6', 'class7' ]

Comment: How can I create my target labels to each image and also I have two types of images such as MVII_C_1.jpg and V2_C_1.jpg both belong to class 'C' but how can write the same in your code.

Comment: You can iterate over the files and check if the name contains the letter say 'C' then save in folder C, this is a separate issue that you have to look up or create a new thread for it.